# nft images not showing on testnets.opensea.io

Tags: solidity, ipfs, nft

Can anyone answer a question for me?  I want to know if I'm using pinata correctly.  I created a small collection (50 images).  Of course there are corresponding .json files for the metadata of each image.  I uploaded the 50 images to pinata, then wrote a script that updated the .json files, so the metadata points to the ipfs location for each image.  I finally uploaded the 50 .json files to pinata as well.  Therefore, the images and the corresponding .json files have different CIDs.  Is this the correct way to do this.  I'm asking because my images are not showing on testnets.opensea.io. My nft contract sets the base uri to the CID of the metadata files (.json files).

Answer (score 0):

What I usually do is upload a folder containing the JSON metadata of the nfts, so that each file is pointing to the same base URI. Then just set your contract to point your nfts to that base URI, and then just add the nft id to the end. If your JSON has the necessary properties, it should show up correctly on opensea. Be sure that each metadata points to its corresponding image.